# When I use scanf(), I wonder what is different in these two

Tags: c

I don't know how to explain this in words, so I'll leave you a question first. So if you had the same question before, please forgive me.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d %d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d %d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I always wondered the difference with `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);` and `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);` when I code. So my question is, are these two codes functionally the same or not?

Comment: It's exactly the same because `%d` consumes leading whitespace

Comment: If these are exactly the same, what do you prefer when you code?

Comment: I prefer not to use scanf at all

Comment: Second snippet says: "ignore optional leading whitespace and read an integer, then ignore optional leading whitespace and read an integer"; first snippet says: "ignore optional leading whitespace and read an integer, then ignore optional whitespace, then ignore optional leading whitespace and read an integer". Difference in execution time should be minimal (something like one clock cycle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are exactly the same.

Many format specifiers consume leading whitespace.  `d` is one of them.  The space character in the format string is an explicit request to consume whitespace.  They are only needed before non-whitespace-consuming format specifiers — `c`, `[`, and `n`.

Whether to include the space character is matter of style.

---

Standard reference: N1570 [7.21.6.2/5 The `fscanf` function](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=335):

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no  more characters can be read.  The directive
>   never fails.

[7.21.6.2/8](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=336):

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function)
>   are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n`
>   specifier.<sup>284)</sup>
>
> <sup>284) These white-space characters are not counted against a
>   specified field width.</sup>

[7.21.6.4/2 The `scanf` function](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=343):

> The `scanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf` with the argument
>   `stdin` interposed before the arguments to `scanf`.

Comment: Then, if I use anything other than %c, I don't have to write spaces and if I use %c, I have to write spaces properly, right?

Comment: @Sam Yes, you are right.  The only non-whitespace-consuming specifiers are `%[`, `%c`, and `%n`, possibly with modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no difference** between the **two snippets of code**. Either way works and you can use whichever one you prefer.

However, if consider the %c i.e. the char data type specifier, then things get interesting. In order the understand the difference consider the following program:

```c
    int main()
    {
        char x,y; //declaring two variable of char data type
        printf("Part 1");
        scanf("%c%c",&x,&y); //no space between the specifiers
        printf("%c %c",x,y);
        printf("Part 2");
        scanf("%c %c",&x,&y); //single white space between the specifiers.
        printf("%c %c",x,y);
        return 0;
    }
```

**A screenshot of the program when it is executed**
[image]

In part 1, variable x stores the char "A" and variable y store " "(whitespace). In this case the space is considered as an input and hence the real input is neglected.
In part 2, variable x store "A" and y stores "B", since it is explicitly mentioned that the whitespace is expected in input.

Hope this helps :)